# What is the uncertainty of a Poisson mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, data-analysis

Suppose I observe $\bar{x}$ occurrences in a relatively large time interval $t,$ and I know that the probability distribution is a Poisson distribution: $P(x) = \frac{e^{-\mu}\mu^{x}}{x!},$ where $\mu$ is the true mean in a time interval $t$. (Also assume $\mu$ is reasonably large enough that my observation $\bar{x}$ is decent.)

What would be the uncertainty in my estimate for the true mean $\mu$? I have seen sources before take the uncertainty to be $\sqrt{\bar{x}}$, because this corresponds to the theoretical standard deviation, so my estimate for the mean would be $\mu = \bar{x} \pm \sqrt{\bar{x}}$.

But *generally,* isn't the uncertainty normally taken to be the *variance?* In that case, my guess for the mean would be $\mu =\bar{x} \pm \bar{x},$ but this seems incorrect.

To take the question one step further, suppose I have $N$ sample observances of $\bar{x}$ each for time intervals $t: \bar{x}_1, \bar{x}_2, ... , \bar{x}_3.$

To estimate $\mu$ I could take the *weighted* mean by assigning an uncertainty to each:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{x_i w_i}{w_i}.$$
Taking $w_i = 1/\sigma_i^2,$ is not uncommon, but would lead to the clearly incorrect result:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{x_i/x_i}{1/x_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i.$$
So taking $w_i = 1/\sigma_i$ seems reasonable here. But if this is the case, why is it more common to see $w_i = 1/\sigma_i^2?$

Comment: If you observe a Poisson process $N_t$ over a large time interval $[0,t]$ and if $\lambda$ is not ridiculously small, then $Z=(N_t-\lambda t)/\sqrt{\lambda t}$ is approximately $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ so you can obtain a classic confidence interval for an estimator $\hat{\lambda}$ of $\lambda$ using the normal distribution (if you have repeated iid observations $N_1(t), \dotsc, N_n(t)$ you can estimate $\lambda$ as the sample mean of the $N_i$ divided by $t$).

Comment: "Uncertainty" is not a mathematically precise term. But the quantity "mean $\pm$ variance" is *never* worth considering, because the units don't match up! (The units on variance are the square of the units on the mean.) So out of the two quantities, only "mean $\pm$ standard deviation" can make sense.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, interesting point. So when I say, “generally, isn’t the uncertainty taken to be the variance?” Is that just an incorrect generalization? It has been a while, but  I can try to find whatever reference gave me this impression

Comment: @Jbag1212 Variance (and standard deviation) are rigorously defined quantities that *attempt* to measure uncertainty, but uncertainty is a more vague idea. Sometimes variance is a useful measure of uncertainty, sometimes it is not. For an example where I think variance is *not* a good metric, suppose that Alice flips a coin to decide between the numbers $0$ and $1$, and Bob flips a coin to decide between the numbers $0$ and $10$. Would you say that you're $10$ times (or $100$ times) more uncertain about Bob's decision than about Alice's?

Comment: @MishaLavrov 10 times more uncertain. Also, it makes more sense “in general”to me for the term uncertainty to mean standard deviation. The context here was about taking a weighted mean to estimate the true mean; what type of weight should be used if the underlying distribution is known to be Poissonian?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I believe a book about error estimates for the physical sciences defined the weight in general to be the inverse variance. But I will maybe start a new question

Answer (score 1):

**Some basics:**
If $N$ has a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda$, then the probability mass function is
$$P(N=n) = \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda}$$
If $N_t$ is a Poisson *process* then for each fixed $t>0$, $N_t$ has the PMF of a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda t$, i.e.
$$P(N_t=n) = \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda t}.$$

In any case if the mean rate is large, say $>1000$, then the scaled RV converges in distribution to a standard normal RV, i.e.
$$Z_\lambda = \frac{N-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \stackrel{d}{\to} Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1),$$
as $\lambda \to \infty$. What do we mean by this?

The expression
$$ Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
means
$$P(Z\leq z) = \Phi(z)$$
where $\Phi$ is the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (CDF) of a standard normal RV, i.e.
$$\Phi(z) = \int_{-\infty}^z \phi(z)dz,$$
where the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) (PDF) $\phi$ is
$$\phi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}.$$

The expression
$$Z_\lambda \stackrel{d}{\to} Z$$
means that CDF of $Z_\lambda$ converges, pointwise, at the points $z$ of continuity, to the CDF of $Z$, i.e.
$$P(Z_\lambda \leq z) \to P(Z\leq z) = \Phi(z).$$
This means that approximately, for large $\lambda$,
$$P(N\leq n) \approx \Phi\left(\frac{n-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)$$

Now, suppose we look at the process $N_t$ over a large time interval $[0,t]$, with $\lambda >0$ fixed. If $t$ is large and $\lambda$ is not ridiculously small, then $\lambda t$ will be large, and we have, approximately,
$$P(N_t \leq n) \approx \Phi\left( \frac{n-\lambda t}{\sqrt{\lambda t}}\right).$$

**Some statistics:**
How is this useful for finding [confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval)? Let's consider the process case, and we have observations $N_1(t),\dotsc, N_n(t)$ for some large time interval $[0,t]$. Take the sample mean
$$\hat{N}_t = \frac{1}{n} (N_1(t)+\dotsc +N_n(t)).$$
This has mean $=\lambda t$, and variance
$$\operatorname{Var}(\hat{N}_t) = \frac{1}{n^2} n \operatorname{Var}(N_1(t))$$
$$ = \frac{1}{n} \lambda t $$
so the standard deviation is $\sqrt{\lambda t/n}$.
It follows that
$$\sqrt{n}\frac{(\hat{N}_t-\lambda t)}{\sqrt{\lambda t}} \to Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1).$$
This means for large $t$ and large $n$, we have, approximately
$$P(\hat{N}_t \leq x ) = \Phi \left(\frac{x-\lambda t}{\sqrt{\lambda t/n}}\right).$$

So what? Well, if we remember that $|x|\leq n$ if and only if $-n \leq x \leq n$ and that distribution functions satisfy $P(a<X<b)=F(b)-F(a)$, where $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$, then we want the difference between the true mean $\lambda t$ and our estimate $\hat{N}_t$ to be small, less than $\epsilon >0$, i.e.
\begin{align*}
P(|\hat{N}_t -\lambda t| \leq \epsilon) &= P(\hat{N}_t-\lambda t \leq \epsilon)-P(\hat{N}_t-\lambda t \leq -\epsilon)\\
& \approx \Phi \left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\lambda t/n}}\right)-\Phi \left(\frac{-\epsilon}{\sqrt{\lambda t/n}}\right)\\
& = \Phi \left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\lambda t/n}}\right)-\left(1-\Phi \left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\lambda t/n}}\right)\right)\\
& = 2\Phi \left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\lambda t/n}}\right)-1.
\end{align*}

Pick your favorite number $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and now say, we want the deviation from the mean to be equal to $1-\alpha$, i.e.
$$P(|\hat{N}_t -\lambda t| \leq \epsilon) = 1-\alpha.$$
Use the approximate normal expression we just found above and solve for $\epsilon$ or $n$, depending on your viewpoint:
$$1-\alpha = 2\Phi \left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\lambda t/n}}\right)-1$$
Add one, divide by $2$ and take the inverse CDF, i.e. the [quantile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) function obtaining
$$\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\lambda t/n}} = \Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)=:z_{\alpha/2},$$
where the RHS is just convenient notation. Thus, if we want an error of $\epsilon$, we can find out how many samples $n$ we need,
by
$$\sqrt{n} \geq \frac{\sqrt{\lambda t}}{\epsilon} z_{\alpha/2}$$
and if instead, we are stuck with merely $n$ samples, the best we can do error wise is
$$\epsilon = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda t}{n}} z_{\alpha/2}.$$
Notice for $\lambda t$ sufficiently large but fixed, the error goes to zero as $n\to \infty$.

The $(1-\alpha)100\%$ confidence interval for $\lambda t$ is now
$$\left[\hat{N}_t - \sqrt{\frac{\lambda t}{n}} z_{\alpha/2}, \hat{N}_t + \sqrt{\frac{\lambda t}{n}} z_{\alpha/2}\right].$$

**Caveat:**
Of course, since this requires the standard deviation and in the Poisson case, this is equal to the square root of the mean, this whole estimate is a little bit silly: we have an error estimate of the mean, that depends on the mean itself! Certainly this is no good. We can rectify this by merely replacing the standard deviation with the sample standard deviation and replacing the normal distribution with [Student's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) $t$-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

Hope this helps and is not too overwhelming. Please comment for corrections, clarifications, or suggestions.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. Because you asked for feedback: I think it would be more useful for me, and perhaps others with a similar level of background, if you started with a “key takeaways” early on that are readily accessible, and then gradually build the complexity and add more detail from there. At present, I have upvoted this, but I have not marked it as accepted, because I don’t understand it well enough, and so I don’t feel like my question was “resolved.”

Comment: @Jbag1212 Thanks for the feedback. If I get some time this week I will try to modify the post to better address your question and make it more digestible.